# Why mix infoJobs with SO jobs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, blog

Today, I received a message telling me that Stack Overflow is partnering with InfoJobs to bring more opportunities. Here is the blog article: [Stack Overflow & InfoJobs: Bringing Opportunities to Developers in Spain](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/31/stack-overflow-infojobs-bringing-opportunities-to-developers-in-spain/)

I tend to think that the jobs offered by Stack Overflow are very interesting. 
I think jobs in InfoJobs are mostly crap.

I don't want MORE opportunities; I want EXCELLENT opportunities!

Comment: Money, presumably.

Comment: Wait, why is this being closed?  This seems like half-feedback here, and especially since the OP is from Spain, they'd be on the front lines to be able to *provide* this feedback.

Comment: Made it a bit clear to show that you're just not ranting on some topic, but providing feedback for a highly relevant blog post.

Comment: A bit of insight from a Spaniard here: InfoJobs has been long seen as a jobs website where you cannot find anything since all offers have hundreds of applicants. No one from my circle ever considers using it to find a job.

Comment: @fedorqui but if they have many applicants, then it means that it's popular... and "crap" are usually, not popular..

Comment: I'm from Spain and i'm totally agree, SO Jobs was a really great tool. Now is full of bad job offers because of the integration with infoJobs. At least let us chose this as a config parameter or something. Really disappointed about this change.